# Visual Studio Code: OSError: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, proxy

I am running the Visual Studio Code behind a Company proxy on windows with Python 3.9.0. And when I try to use the command:

```
pip install pandas
```

in the terminal, it leads to the following error (note that it could be every other pip install package):

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Proxy URL had no
> scheme, should start with http:// or https://

[image]

My json.file looks like:

```
{
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": true,
    "update.mode": "none",
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a URL & Proximity issue, not related to vscode. You can Google the solution for this error.

Comment: the funny part is, that it still works, if I select another kernel in visual studio code...when I select an "old" kernel which in installed 3 weeks ago, it still works...

Comment: Why not consider that there is a problem with this kernel? If it is a virtual environment, creating a new one directly would be a faster and more effective method.

Comment: thats what I did and i am not able to configure the new enviornment then...due to the errors

Comment: I think you can add the steps on how to create the environment to the article, you can also refer to [the document about creating the virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment-in-the-terminal).

Comment: the enviornment is created...thats not the problem, it fails when I want to add new packages to the enviorment, also when its succesfully activated. Visual Studio Code only allows me to install packages in old enviornments...local and virtual ones...for new it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was hidden in the local set-up for windows:

> Windows menu--> type "env" --> select: "edit the system enviornmental
> variables" --> click "enviornment variables " and I need to add:
> "http:thisismyproxy" and "https:thisismyproxy" to the http and https proxy lines

So the error was, that the pip used the old proxy format "thisismyproxy" instead of "http:thisismyproxy"